# Navigation bar is showing in storyboard but not simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

The following is my storyboard ,

and the ViewController(CaseInfo or VC2) is showing the navigation bar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgjg9.png

but in my simulator the navigation bar dosen't show up !

In VC1(CaseList):
 I make the VC1 be the rootView of the navigation controller

and I link the VC1 to VC2 with choosing "push" option

then I use the code when I click the table item of VC1:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CaseList *tagEditor = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CaseInfo"];
    [self presentViewController:tagEditor animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But the Navigation bar in VC2 doesn't show up

Please Help Me...

Thank you!!

-

btw

I also use the code in VC2(CaseInfo)

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO       animated:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code,since you have linked the VC2 and VC1 with a segue

you just need to fire it

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueid" sender:nil];
}
```

Then in `prepareForSegue`,pass some data.

**Or**

You can delete the segue between VC2 and VC1

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CaseList *tagEditor = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CaseInfo"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tagEditor animated:true];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You solve my problem immediately and you save my day :)